# How to fetch an array of image URLs with node.js and save to s3 asynchronously?

Tags: node.js

I'm uploading arrays of image urls to save to S3.  The code works, but it is not executing asynchronously.  Time stamping to the console appears to show that first all the images are fetched and buffered, and then they are sequentially saved to s3. I ran an array of 100 images, and the first image was not submitted to s3 until the 100th had been fetched.  At least it appears that way as I get a stream of timestamps in the console from the image request callbacks, and the "saving to s3" timestamps don't start until the last image callback has been timestamped.  I'm fairly new to node, and after two days of experimentation I haven't cracked this.

I've also tried piping it directly, but that requires all files to have content-length set, and some will not.  I originally had the getImageFromUrl in a single function, but broke it down into three separate smaller ones to help with figuring out where the problem lies. I'm using request, knox for s3, and caolan's async library for the async.each iterator.  The code is as follows:

```
var images2get = req.body.images2get;  // an array of image urls to be fetched and saved to s3
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

//iterate over the array and get each image, save to S3 
var imageNumber = 0;  // this needs to come before the iterator so it's defined

    async.each(images2get, getImageFromUrl, function(err){
        if(err) {
           console.log('async each failed for images2get');
        } else {
           res.send(200);
        }
    });

function getImageFromUrl(url2fetch, nextImage){
    var options = {encoding: null,
                    url: url2fetch, 
                    method: 'GET',
                    timeout: 10*1000
                    }
    request(options, function(err, fetchResponse, body){
        if(!err && fetchResponse && fetchResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            nextImage();  //we've got the image, call the iterator to fetch the next one
            var s3Config = prepareImageForS3(fetchResponse, url2fetch);
            saveToS3(body, s3Config);
        } else {
        //there was a problem fetching the url
        console.log('Error ' + fetchResponse.statusCode + ' Failed to get image from ', url2fetch.absolute);
        nextImage();
        }    
    });
};

function prepareImageForS3(fetchResponse, url2fetch) {
    console.log('preparing image ' + imageNumber + ' at ', (Date.now() - startTime));
    imageNumber += 1;
    var filename = '/' + userId + '/' + pageId + '/image' + imageNumber;
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': fetchResponse.headers['content-type'],
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
    };
    return{
        'filename': filename,
        'filetype': 'image',
        'filenumber': imageNumber,
        'headers': headers,
        'replaceSrc': true,
        'url': url2fetch
    };
};

function saveToS3(file, s3Config) {
    s3Client.putBuffer(file, s3Config.filename, s3Config.headers, function(err, res){
        console.log('image ' + imageNumber + ' submitting to s3 at ', (Date.now() - startTime));
        //console.log('response from s3 save from url, status:', res.statusCode, 'url:', res.req.url);
        if(!err && res.statusCode === 200 && s3Config.replaceSrc) {
            console.log('image ' + imageNumber + ' saved to s3 at ', (Date.now() - startTime));
        } else {
            console.log('failed to save image to S3 from ' + res.req.url)
        }    
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could improve with your code:

- HTTP Agent

First of all, node.js uses an [HTTP Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent), which limits the number of concurrent connections to a host. If it wasn't, you could easily accidentally hammer websites with thousands of connections.

You can disable it by passing `{agent: false}` to request. Note that knox [already disables it](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/blob/master/lib/client.js#L256).

I suspect this is the reason why your code runs sequentially.

- Async.each

Async.each will run all iterations in parallel. When you are calling `nextImage()`, you are not telling async to start the next iteration, but rather say that you are done. Async completes when all iterations are done. The problem here is that you keep doing work after you told async that you were finished.